# kafka incremental aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a stream `delta` of numbers in a kafka topic that needs to be aggregated in a special way, i.e.:

```
aggregate[0] = 0
aggregate[N] = aggregate[N-1] * (N - 1) / N + delta[N - 1] / N
```

(exact formula is irrelevant, note the dependency on the previous element in `aggregate` though)

Essentially, I need to subscribe to two kafka topics simultaneously, where I advance in both topics at the same time: when I read an item in the `delta` topic, I need to read the the corresponding item from the `aggregate` topic as well, and write the result into the the `aggregate` topic, before the next item in the `delta` topic is consumed.

Is this at all possible in kafka? Could ksql with a clever join help?

Comment: please note that there are no guarantees about the order of elements within in a topic. You can only have this on partition level.

Comment: @TobiSH I guess that's fine for me, as long it's not resulting in a race condition

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether my pseudocode could helps.
Assume that there are two topics, "delta" and "aggregate".
And partition of both topic is 1 to simplify situation(so that we get global order)

```
# this is just pseudocode to show my thoughts
def demo():
    delta_consumer = Consumer("delta")
    aggregate_consumer = Consumer("aggregate")
    aggregate_producer = Producer("aggregate")

    is_pre_aggregate_result_exists = aggregate_consumer.get_offset() != 0 # check whether it's first running 
    for delta_data in delta_consumer.poll():
        if not is_pre_aggregate_result_exists:
            last_aggregate_result = 0
        else:
            last_aggregate_result = aggregate_consumer.get_last_record()
        new_aggregate_result = user_define_function(delta_data, last_aggregate_result)
        aggregate_producer.producer(new_aggregate_result)
        is_pre_aggregate_result_exists = True
```

Meanwhile, I guess that kafka+structurd-steaming could handle your problem because the internal need of your question is to get aggregate_result on a stream table and then output result to kafka topic, where kafka+structured-steraming is a perfect solution.

Comment: This works, I'd say, but only if there is exactly one such worker, right? If we want to scale this, doesn't this result in a race condition that two workers read the value from `aggregate` simultaneously, then proceed to compute the new value, then write to `aggregate`. Or am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: In fact I don't think that mutil-worker is necessary if you just need to calculate such aggregate result on values.If there are complex logics, please considering about kafka+structured-streaming, which is a better plan.